# Json error plugin Neo4j

Tags: java, json, plugins, neo4j, server

I make an error when execute my plugin in neo4j server when manage a json object from any json library.

```
    http://localhost:7474/ is ready.
{
  "message" : "org/json/simple/JSONArray",
  "exception" : "NoClassDefFoundError",
  "fullname" : "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError",
  "stackTrace" : [ "com.geoblink.neonetwork.Network.getDrivingPolygon(Network.java:176)", "com.geoblink.neonetwork.GeoblinkRouting.getDrivingPolygon(GeoblinkRouting.java:25)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginMethod.invoke(PluginMethod.java:61)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.invoke(PluginManager.java:158)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:312)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:134)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)", "ch.qos.logback.access.servlet.TeeFilter.doFilter(TeeFilter.java:55)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CollectUserAgentFilter.doFilter(CollectUserAgentFilter.java:69)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)" ],
  "cause" : {
    "message" : "org.json.simple.JSONArray",
    "errors" : [ {
      "message" : "org.json.simple.JSONArray",
      "code" : "Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownFailure",
      "stackTrace" : "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.JSONArray\n\tat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)\n\tat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)\n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)\n\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)\n\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)\n\tat sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)\n\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)\n\tat com.geoblink.neonetwork.Network.getDrivingPolygon(Network.java:176)\n\tat com.geoblink.neonetwork.GeoblinkRouting.getDrivingPolygon(GeoblinkRouting.java:25)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)\n\tat org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginMethod.invoke(PluginMethod.java:61)\n\tat org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.invoke(PluginManager.java:158)\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:312)\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:134)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:800)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)\n\tat ch.qos.logback.access.servlet.TeeFilter.doFilter(TeeFilter.java:55)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CollectUserAgentFilter.doFilter(CollectUserAgentFilter.java:69)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:95)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\n"
    } ],
    "exception" : "ClassNotFoundException",
    "fullname" : "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException",
    "stackTrace" : [ "java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)", "java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)", "java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)", "java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)", "java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)", "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)", "java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)", "com.geoblink.neonetwork.Network.getDrivingPolygon(Network.java:176)", "com.geoblink.neonetwork.GeoblinkRouting.getDrivingPolygon(GeoblinkRouting.java:25)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginMethod.invoke(PluginMethod.java:61)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.invoke(PluginManager.java:158)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:312)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:134)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)", "ch.qos.logback.access.servlet.TeeFilter.doFilter(TeeFilter.java:55)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CollectUserAgentFilter.doFilter(CollectUserAgentFilter.java:69)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)" ]
  },
  "errors" : [ {
    "message" : "org/json/simple/JSONArray",
    "code" : "Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownFailure",
    "stackTrace" : "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/JSONArray\n\tat com.geoblink.neonetwork.Network.getDrivingPolygon(Network.java:176)\n\tat com.geoblink.neonetwork.GeoblinkRouting.getDrivingPolygon(GeoblinkRouting.java:25)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)\n\tat org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginMethod.invoke(PluginMethod.java:61)\n\tat org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.invoke(PluginManager.java:158)\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:312)\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:134)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:800)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)\n\tat ch.qos.logback.access.servlet.TeeFilter.doFilter(TeeFilter.java:55)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CollectUserAgentFilter.doFilter(CollectUserAgentFilter.java:69)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:95)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\nCaused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.JSONArray\n\tat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)\n\tat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)\n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)\n\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)\n\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)\n\tat sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)\n\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)\n\t... 55 more\n"
  } ]
```

I use sentences in my function as:

```
JSONArray arrayNodesOut = new JSONArray();

JSONParser parse = new JSONParser();
Object obj = parse.parse(node.getProperty("geojson").toString());
arrayNodesOut.add(obj);
```

Has someone any solution to the problem?...

Many thanks!

Comment: can you please provide your pom.xml? seems like a dependency error.

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin is complied fine so it means you have this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20160212</version>
</dependency>
```

But when you deploy the plugin, it throws ClassNotFoundException. It means json jar is not there on Neo4j class path. Either add json.jar to the Neo4j class path or create "fat jar" for you plugin.
See  [here](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/) or [here](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-create-a-fat-jar-file-one-jar-example/) how.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.

Only I included de library jars into neo4j lib directory.